# select first day of previous month from record in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that has a column called `StartDateTime` that stores datetime values. I need a statement that will return the date of the first day in the previous month of the current record. So, if the stored date is `2006-06-17 08:23:42.000` the statement would return `2006-05-01 00:00:00.000` and importantly if the stored date is `2006-01-17 08:23:42.000` the statement would return `2005-11-1 00:00:00.000`

If I could use `DATEBYPARTS` this seems like it would be simple, but unfortunately I can not.
I tried using

```
CAST( 
   CAST( Year([StartDateTime]) as varchar(4) ) 
   + '-' + 
   CAST( (Month([StartDateTime])-1) as varchar(2) ) 
   + '-' + 
   CAST( '1' as varchar(2) ) 
AS DATETIME )
```

but it errors on January 1st dates and gives error "The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, StartDateTime) - 1, 0)
from <yourtable>
```

Or, as Aaron Bertrand suggested in comments, more clear way

```
select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, StartDateTime) - 1, 0)
from <yourtable>
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8)

Comment: Please use `MONTH` instead of shorthand like `mm`. Why? Well, check out what `w` and `y` do. Probably not what you expected. Type what you mean instead of lazy shortcuts. Please.